# Angular async service

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angular-services, angularjs-http

I'm trying to do an ajax call via `$http` service inside a custom service. Then I want to customize, inside my controller, the data received in the custom service.

I wrap the customizing data function within `$interval` inside the controller: by this way I can customize my data when it is received.

**The problem is**: while the data is correctly logged in the service, **the service seems like it doesn't return anything**, although it should have returned (`return response.data.Items`)

So `$interval` loops indefinitely, and I can't customize my data.

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);


myApp.service('ajaxcall', ['$http', function($http) {

    this.getjson = function () {

        $http.get("http://localhost:3000/one")
            .then(function(response) {

            console.log(response.data.Items);  //data logged correctly
            return response.data.Items;
        });
    }
}])

.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$interval', 'ajaxcall', function($scope, $interval, ajaxcall) {

    var new_items = ajaxcall.getjson();

    customize_data = $interval(function () {  //loops indefintely, new_items=undefined, why?
                         if (new_items) {
                             // customize data
                         }
                     }, 200);

    for(var i=0; i<new_items.length; i++) {
        $scope.items.push(new_items[i]);
    }
}]);
```

You could say: just move the customize data function in the custom service. First at all I don't want to do it. Secondly it doesn't even make sense: the $scope is not available in a service, so in any case I should wait for the $http reply.

Comment: use promise inside your service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several things which I wanted to point out there.

1. Do return `$http` promise from `this.getjson` method, so that you can chain that promise while getting data from it.

   ```
   this.getjson = function() {
     //returned promise here
     return $http.get("http://localhost:3000/one")
       .then(function(response) {
       console.log(response.data.Items); //data logged correctly
       return response.data.Items;
     });
   }
   ```

---

2. `var new_items = ajaxcall.getjson()` line doesn't stored the data returned by `getjson` call, it will have undefined value as your currently getting. After finish up above change, `new_items` will hold promise return by `ajaxcall.getjson`. Thereafter use `$q.when` to keep eye on promise to get resolved & check for data inside its `.then` function.

   ```
   customize_data = $interval(function() { //loops indefintely, new_items=undefined, why?
     $q.when(new_items).then(function(res) {
       if (customizeData) {
         //Do Logic
       }
     })
   }, 200);
   ```

> **Side Note:** You could face problem with this code, as you had `200ms` time for each interval . Which can make multiple ajax calls before completing the last call(which would be kind of unexpected behaviour). To
>   resolve such issue you could use `$interval.cancel(customize_data);
>   //once desired interval work has done`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What's the best approach in your opinion? Someone has answered me to use a factory instead of a service, what do you think?
About the side note: actually I've deleted `$interval.cancel` in the example because I don't know where to put it. Just below `$interval` ? I don't think it is safe. Or do you mean inside `if (customizeData)`?

Comment: Ok it works by putting `$interval.cancel` inside `$interval`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the return data, you would write a factory instead of service!

code:

```
myApp.factory('ajaxcall', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    getjson : function () {

        $http.get("http://localhost:3000/one")
            .then(function(response) {

            console.log(response.data.Items);  //data logged correctly
            return response.data.Items;
        });
    }
}
}])
```

Comment: I'll try it, but I've learned the service pattern on w3schools. Please give it a look on the "Create Your Own Service" section. http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_services.asp
Why shouldn't it work in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing the `promise` returned by your asynchronous call. Here is what you need to do in your controller to change the data:

```
ajaxcall.getjson()
.then(function(new_items) {
    // customize data

    // this part should go here as well
    for(var i=0; i<new_items.length; i++) {
      $scope.items.push(new_items[i]);
    }
});
```

No need to use `intervals` or `timeouts`. Pay attention, `ajaxcall.getjson()` does **NOT** return your data, it returns the promise resolved with your items.

Read about the [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) in angular.

Answer (score 0):

use promise when your making http calls from service

```
myApp.service('ajaxcall', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {
    this.getjson = function() {
      var q = $q.defer();
      $http.get("http://localhost:3000/one")
        .success(function(data) {
          console.log(data); //data logged correctly
          q.resolve(data);
        })
      .error(function(err) {
        q.reject(err);
      });
      return q.promise;
    }
  }]);
```

changes in controller to wait for promise

```
ajaxcall.getjson()
 .then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
 });
```